# Prove that $\{f_n\}$ converge a $f$ in weak dual topology iff $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f_n(x)=f(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ a normed space. $\{f_n\}$ a sequence in $X^*$ and $f\in X^*$.

Prove that $\{f_n\}$ converge a $f$ in weak dual topology iff:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f_n(x)=f(x)$$ for all $x\in X$

**My attempt:**

$(\implies)$  As $\{f_n\}$ converge a f in weak dual topology then:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}T(f_n)=T(f)$$

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f_n \to f$ in the weak topology. Then, for any $x \in X$ and $\epsilon >0$, $\{g: |g(x)-f(x)| <\epsilon\}$ is a weakly open set containing $f$. Hence it contains $f_n$ for $n$ sufficiently large. This means $|f_n(x)-f(x)| <\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Converse part: Suppose $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for every $x \in X$. A basic weak neighborhood of $f$ is of the type $\{g: |g(x_i)-f(x_i)| <\epsilon_i, 1\leq i \leq N\}$. Can you show that this neighborhood contains $f_n$ for  $n$ sufficiently large?